# Performance of Modbus RTU server

Tags: python-3.x, modbus, rs485, pymodbus

I am developing a Modbus server using pymodbus v2.5.3 synchronous server and RTU framer. The client is sending requests @600ms.

The broadcast requests received as following bytes have to be ignored: `00 2b 0d 01 01 7c 77`
MEI type function code 43 with device ID 1 as following bytes `01 2b 0e 01 b4 70` has to be answered with device identification info.
I am just trying to receive all requests without replying to see the performance. The framer loses half of the packets in frame checker stage or ignores it. I tried to set the serial socket with a lower timeout of 500ms or even higher value of 3s but the framer still loses half of the frames.
Can the framer work at below 1s limit because it loses half of the requests sent by client? Server log indicating these errors is attached.

[Server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpiPF.jpg)

Comment: I cannot see any obvious reason that this could not work (from a quick scan through the library code) but obviously your code is a factor. Can you please post more info; logs would be ideal but also some supporting info (baud rate, what hardware is this running on, your code, what "does not send proper responses" actually means etc).

Comment: @Brits-I have added the code snippet, serial settings and logs

Comment: If you want to ignore broadcasts its better to set [`broadcast_enable=false`](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/pymodbus/server/sync.py#L556). You may find that the `dev` branch works better (some improvements have been made to the way the library determines how [many bytes to expect](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/commit/2f92ce891b95c5fc412cfddc3c946a44833089d2).

Comment: @Brits...After doing more analysis, I found out that setting timeout to any value between 0-3 sec, framer checking fails or frames are ignored. So, is it because the client is faster and framer can't take frames sent below 1s rate?

Comment: Computers 20 years ago could cope with serial traffic so I doubt it's a performance issue (but you have not provided much of the information requested so I'm guessing). The algorithm that pymodbus uses to find frames is not particularly sophisticated and does not understand CANopen messages (`2B 0D`) messages so it's unsurprising that you are getting erratic results. I'd suggest adding support for those messages to the library (even if it's just so they can be ignored).

Comment: Yes, serial timeout can be set to ms level but that does not change the behaviour of the framer. The client begins with CANopen messages followed by read/write register requests @660ms and each request needs to be responded within 500ms. (2B 0D) messages are implemented in the pymodbus so that's why I used this library. Even for function codes 03 & 10, framer responds to half of the requests only. As a result, client drops the connection with the server.

Comment: "(`2B 0D`) messages are implemented in the pymodbus" are you sure? It handles `2B 0E` [here](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/dev/pymodbus/mei_message.py#L48) but I don't see any code to handle `2B 0D` (so when one of those messages is received it will sit in the frame buffer until the timeout expires).

Comment: Thanks @Brits for the correction. The client sends (2B 0D) as a broadcast first which need not be answered by the server. So, I ignore these with the flag as you had suggested. Then, the client sends (2B 0E) requests which are responded by the server. These pair of messages are retried by the client 10 times and the server is able to respond within first 5 times as the framer loses half of the requests here also. Afterwards, for function codes 03 & 10, framer responds to half of the requests only.

Comment: From the logs I suspect the `2b 0d` is the issue; the framer cannot work out the packet length so it just receives data until the timeout and then throws anything received away (I can't see any code that searches for another packet in the buffer). This leads to the intermittent results you see.